# Proper syntax for calling values from appsettings.json instead of using literal string

Tags: c#, asp.net

While there are a myriad of threads on here about this subject, the ones I looked at did not address my exact need.

ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web app:

I have a C# method that looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace ClientsUI.Data
{
    public class ClientsService
    {
        private readonly ClientsDbContext _context;
        private readonly IConfiguration _iconfiguration;

        public ClientsService(ClientsDbContext context, IConfiguration iconfiguration)
        {
            _context = context;
            _iconfiguration = iconfiguration;
        }
    

        public async Task<List<BillingCodes>>
        GetBillingCodesNameTestAsync()

        {
        return await _context.BillingCodes.Where(c => c.Name.Contains("Test") && c.ClientId.ToString() != "ABC123")
              .AsNoTracking()
              .ToListAsync();
        }
     }   
  }
```

And an `appsettings.json` that looks like this:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },

  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "myconnectionstring"

  },

  "SqlFilters": {
    "NameFilter": "Test",
    "ClientIdFilter": "ABC123"
  }
}
```

In the `GetBillingCodesNameTestAsync` method, I need to replace "Test" and "ABC123" with a call to the `appsettings.json` file, something along the lines of `Configuration.GetSqlFilters...` which I can't get to work properly, hence my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the strongly typed interface available in `IConfiguration`.

```
class SqlFilters {
  string NameFilter { get; set; }
  string ClientIdFilter { get; set; }
}
```

and then use

```
var sqlFilters = _iconfiguration.GetSection("SqlFilters").Get<SqlFilters>();
```

Accessing your variables is then as easy as accessing properties on a class (that is `sqlFilters.NameFilter` and `sqlFilters.ClientIdFilter` respectively).

Comment: ...and adding _services.Configure<SqlFilters>(Configuration.GetSection("SqlFilters"));_ in startup.cs allows your code to use it through Dependency Injection

Comment: @fredrik thanks for this answer.  I'm having trouble with the `var sqlfilters` line - where exactly should I place this - anywhere I place it in my `ClientsService` class file, I get errors.

Comment: Also, just to clarify, I created a new separate class for `SqlFilters` - is this the intent or is this supposed to go in an already existing file?

Comment: @Stpete111 You can (and normally should) use a separate file, yes. I'd recommend you to read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1, and what you should use for this (there are too many examples unfortunately) should follow what is done in the code block that has `services.Configure<PositionOptions>` and how to use it is shown in the example directly below

Comment: @Stpete111 You should have it in the function where you need to use the variables. But you should take Camilo's suggestion and read up on how to use the `services.Configure` approach as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
return await _context.BillingCodes.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(_iconfiguration["SqlFilters:NameFilter"]) && c.ClientId.ToString() != _iconfiguration["SqlFilters:ClientIdFilter"])
              .AsNoTracking()
              .ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend **strongly** against this. Not only is dirty; it's also easy to have a typo, it creates a dependency to the configuration system, it makes ASP.NET Core create the service using a bigger-than-required object, there used to be a memory leak around injecting IConfiguration directly, last-yet-most-important using a strongly-typed approach is extremely simple

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto there's more than one way to skin a cat. I just provided one. I think if you are suggesting something else you should maybe point to an example or give a different answer with code that shows what you propose. Otherwise you are not really helping the OP.